# PHPMailer works on localhost but on but not on server

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a mail that is contents.html to some person, this code works fine on XAMPP but doesn't work on server, just shows empty screen and ends up without sending mail, What am I doing wrong?

**gmail.php**

```
 <?php
    include('/mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    include('/mailer/class.smtp.php'); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded
    $hodemail = strtolower($branch)."hodofsrit@gmail.com";
    echo '1';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    echo '2';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx";
    $mail->SetFrom("134g1a05a1@srit.ac.in");
    $mail->Subject = "Student Feedback ".$branch . " ".$yearandsem;
    $mail->Body = "hello, Here's the graph generated";
    $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
    $mail->AddAddress($hodemail);
     if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            $error = $mail->ErrorInfo;
        header('Location:sendmail.php?errormsg=There was an error in sending email '.$error);
        }
        else
        {
        function redirect($url)
        {
        $string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
        $string .= 'window.location = "' . $url . '"';
        $string .= '</script>';
        echo $string;
        }
       redirect('sendmail.php?msg=Email Successfully sent to corresponding HOD!');
        }
    ?>
```

**send_mail.pgp**

```
<?php 
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
    $branch = $_POST['branch'];
$yearandsem = $_POST['yearandsem'];
 include 'displaygraphs.php';
 include'gmail.php';
 } 
else {
    header('location:index.php?msg="Login First"');
}
?>
```

the displaygraphs is working fine, after I tested with some `echo's`, I came to know that the page is stopping after the line `$mail = new PHPMailer();` line in gmail.php, please help me solve this, Thank You!

Comment: Have you looked at logs for an error message?

Comment: With those `echo` lines in there if `$mail->Send()` fails and it tries to send a header you will get a 'headers already sent' error.

Comment: it says `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/sritsfs/public_html/mysrit/gmail.php on line 6`
and `PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/mailer/class.phpmailer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/sritsfs/public_html/mysrit/gmail.php on line 2`

Comment: The path to the mailer library must be wrong. Where does mailer/ reside?

Comment: `mailer` is a directory that is in the same path as `gmail.php`

Comment: I am getting this error

Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i6sm660006ejd.57 - gsmtp<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
2021-10-08 08:29:28 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2021-10-08 08:29:28 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection i6sm660006ejd.57 - gsmtp<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it fails at `new PHPMailer()`, the library may not be loaded. Check the path to the mailer directory, which looks to be:

`/mysrit/mailer/class.phpmailer.php` (note the beginning / making it absolute)

or

`mailer/class.phpmailer.php` (note the lack of beginning / making the path relative).

I would suggest making the library [required](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). That is:

```
require 'mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
```

or if it might get loaded multiple times:

```
require_once 'mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
```

That way the script will stop execution right when it can't find the mailer library.

Comment: oops!, my bad, thank  you, but now I've changed it, send_email.php keeps loading forever, any reason, or headers already sent problems?

Comment: What is the name of the file? You have referred to it with an underscore, but your code is without the underscore.

Comment: name of the file is 'contents.html' , it has an image embedded into it and is in the same directory as `gmail.php`

Comment: I suggest actually reading the readme that comes with PHPMailer which tells you exactly how you should load the library. Short version: use composer.

Comment: @Synchro, While I agree that dependency managers should be used, they are not a requirement. In fact, you should actually read the ReadMe. In particular the part labeled "Minimal installation".

Comment: I know. I wrote it.

Answer (score 29):

Just comment  `$mail->IsSMTP();` ..I had same problem..On *localhost* its working and on live server not working..After I commented `$mail->IsSMTP();` this, Its working fine..Hopes so might be helpful for u it is.

Comment: +1 thanks. I wasted lot of time figuring out why giving connection errors .. whereas working on my localhost.

Comment: you saved me a headache

Comment: Great!!, Thank you very much

Comment: Doing this means you will not be using SMTP. It's not a real fix for the problem, but just moves it elsewhere. It's like saying that a good way of repairing your car is to walk instead. The PHPMailer documentation will help you figure out exactly what's wrong.

Comment: You saved my life!

Comment: As others have pointed out... DON'T comment out '$mail->IsSMTP();'  as it will ignore SMTP settings!

Comment: ok, it is working, but messages now go to junk mail, any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

If you remove `$mail->IsSMTP()`, you will **NOT** be using `SMTP`! PHPMailer will then use the built-in `mail()` function and all your `SMTP` specific settings will be ignored!

Comment: So what is the solution that will work in the server perfectly?